# Spring Integration route message from Transformer

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have intergration setup as

```
    IntegrationFlows.from("ValidFile")
    .transform(
    Transformer(new FindTheDepartItbelongs()) //basically file has to match to some depoartment
    .transform(new FileParserTransformer()
.transform(new DataSplitterTransformer()
    .transformer(new CustomerTransformer()
    .handle (o -> {})
```

As you see the `DataSplitterTransformer`() basically I have to group the data for example Department ID.

Now lets say I get three records with department id (1 and 3)

I want to pause at DataSplitterTransformer() and route the message to "ValidFile" again

It will be two message 1 for department 1 and one for 3

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration is not clear with such an explanation. Sounds like you are missing the fact that there are `.split()` for producing several output from a single message and also a `.route()` to decide where to send every message according selector logic.

You can really route back to the `ValidFile` channel and also you can continue in the main flow using `defaultOutputToParentFlow()`.

See their Javadocs for more info.

Comment: OK Thanks.I'll have a look. Thanks